# How to convert .gdb database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

1. I have a `.GDB` database (old one) and the data in it is very important
2. I need to convert that `.gdb` database to a SQL Server database - can anyone help me...

Comment: have you looked into SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create connections to both source GDB and Destination SQL Server in ArcCatalog. Copy everything from source and paste it into the destination. You won't be able to do it with SQL tools alone.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking ESRI software, for ***simple*** cases, my workflow is to use the [GDAL C++ API](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716155258/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDataset.html) to read the GDB. This requires the [GDAL File GDB driver](https://gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html). Then I will use **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types** to transfer to SQL Server. This involves low-level APIs and you need to understand the spatial types in the respective libraries. It gets complex if you have polygons with rings, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a tool that will automatically convert between these database types. You'll need to use an application that can read the old database type (Firebase), learn the table design, create a similar table design in SQL Server, and use the application to load the data from Firebase to SQL Server.

Typically, this kind of work is called ETL (Extract/Transform/Load) and is done with migration tools like SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS). SSIS is free with SQL Server, and there are a lot of books available on how to use it - but like learning to develop software, this isn't a small task.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to export Esri File Geodatabase FGDB (.gdb) data to MS SQL Server is with ArcGIS for Desktop at the Standard or Advanced level.

You may also want to try exporting to shapefile (SHP) format (an open transitional format) then import to your MS SQL Server.  I've seen a tool online that has worked for me called Shape2SQL.

Esri also has an open File Geodatabase API that you can use to write your own too.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [FME Workbench](https://www.safe.com/fme) for GIS data conversion. It's like SQL Server Integration Services (ETL) but for GIS.  Graphical interface, connect data readers with data writes, insert transforms, run them, etc.